# How do I write a case statement to return duplicate records?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of names and addresses and want to return the full list of names and addresses with an extra column that identifies if the address is a duplicate or unique address. There are several duplicate address entries that I can see when I run a more simple statement --

```
SELECT PersonAddressLine1, Count (*)
FROM CompanyTable1
GROUP BY PersonAddressLine1
```

or

```
SELECT PersonAddressLine1, Count (*)
FROM CompanyTable1
GROUP BY PersonAddressLine1
HAVING COUNT (*) > 1
```

but I need to return the full table with columns -

```
PersonID, PersonName, PersonAddressLine1, AddressVerification (Duplicate / Unique), CompanyID, CompanyName.

PersonID - 1
PersonID - 2
PersonID - 3
PersonName - Ryan
PersonName - Andrew
PersonName - Ben
PersonAddressLine1 - 100 Avenue
PersonAddressLine1 - 100 Avenue
PersonAddressLine1 - 200 Avenue
```

If I use the below case statement, the group condition impacts the PersonAddressLine1 count result. It shows the addresses all as unique.

```
SELECT PersonID, PersonName, PersonAddressLine1, CompanyID, CompanyName, 

CASE WHEN count(*) > 1 
THEN CONCAT(PersonName,' ','Address Line 1 is duplicate')
    ELSE CONCAT(PersonName,' ','Address Line 1 is unique')
END AS 'Person Address Verification'

FROM CompanyTable1

GROUP by PersonAddressLine1, PersonID, PersonName, CompanyID, CompanyName
```

Comment: what is your goal ? if 2 different `PersonID` having the same `PersonAddressLine1` do you want to consider it as `duplicate` ?

Comment: Yes. I want to see the full results table with just an indicator of whether the one column [PersonAddressLine1] is a duplicate or not.

Comment: put a `row_number() partition by the address`, anything > 1 is a duplicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use window function `COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY PersonAddressLine1)` to count the no of duplicates

```
SELECT PersonID, PersonName, PersonAddressLine1, CompanyID, CompanyName, 
       CASE WHEN COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY PersonAddressLine1) > 1 
            THEN CONCAT(PersonName,' ','Address Line 1 is duplicate')
            ELSE CONCAT(PersonName,' ','Address Line 1 is unique')
            END AS 'Person Address Verification'
FROM   CompanyTable1
```

what your current query is doing right now is not only checking for `PersonAddressLine1` but all of the following
 `PersonAddressLine1, PersonID, PersonName, CompanyID, CompanyName`